# I18n warning when key is overriden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

Is it possible to get a warning from I18n, when a key is already defined, and the merge between files would overwrite another key?

For example, we have these two files:

hello.de.yml

```
de:
  hello:
    world: test1
    foo: bar
```

world.de.yml

```
de:
  hello: Hello world
```

When I call `I18n.t("hello")`, I get `"Hello world"` from the `world.de.yml` file, because it overwrites the whole key and doesn't deep merge it, as it would, when an object lies behind the `hello` key.

> Is it possible to raise an error, when a key is overwritten and not deep merged?

And a similar problems occurs within long YAML files, but this is not within I18n, it's within the parser I think. Consider this file:

```
de:
  hello:
    foo: foo
  hello:
    bar: bar
```

Here, `I18n.t("hello")` returns `{:bar=>"bar"}` (parsed in Ruby) because the last key "wins". I think this is a YAML feature that you can redefine keys and overwrite keys, *but it would be good to raise a warning* if this happens. Can the Ruby YAML parser (or Psych) do something like that? I haven't found an option for that.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question (and I'm not affiliated) but you might get a kick out of https://www.localeapp.com/.

Comment: This might help [YAMLLint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint) and  a [gist](https://gist.github.com/pypt/94d747fe5180851196eb) to find duplicates under same hierarchy. For psych, this [issue](https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/79) is still under development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML does not currently have this feature.

However, for psych, (looks like) this [issue](https://github.com/ruby/psych/issues/79) is still under development.

The following might be of some help.

1. [YAMLLint](https://github.com/adrienverge/yamllint).
2. There is also a good [gist](https://gist.github.com/pypt/94d747fe5180851196eb) to find duplicates under same hierarchy.